# Recurring Events: SharePoint Online's Lists.asmx Service Not Returning Expected Results

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-calendar, recurring-events, asmx

I have the following query which returns some of the recurring events but not all. The query is not returning the items in the correct order, nor is it returning the items after today's date.

How can I modify the query below to return **events that occur after today** and in **ascending order?**

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
      <listName>521dx906-1zdc-429d-b4c8-185fafa88029</listName>
      <query>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <And>
              <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
                <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
              </Eq>
              <DateRangesOverlap>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
                <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
                <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">2019-08-16T14:29:03.361Z</Value>
              </DateRangesOverlap>
            </And>
          </Where>
        </Query>
      </query>
      <viewFields>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Category" />
          <FieldRef Name="Location" />
        </ViewFields>
      </viewFields>
      <queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions>
          <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll" />
          <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
          <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
          <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
        </QueryOptions>
      </queryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

My calendar contains the recurring "Merchandising Notes Posted!" event on the following days:

- 8/17
- 8/24
- 8/31
- etc...

[image]

However, **just two "Merchandising Notes Posted!" events are being returned** from the query above, and one's from last month!

- 7/27
- 8/17

[image]

**Edit:** The query has been updated:

```
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/'>
  <soap:Body>
    <GetListItems xmlns='http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/soap/'>
      <listName>521dx906-1zdc-429d-b4c8-185fafa88029</listName>
      <query>
        <Query>
          <Where>
            <And>
              <Eq>
                <FieldRef Name="fRecurrence" />
                <Value Type="Boolean">1</Value>
              </Eq>
              <DateRangesOverlap>
                <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
                <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
                <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
                <Value Type="DateTime">
                  <Now />
                </Value>
              </DateRangesOverlap>
            </And>
          </Where>
          <OrderBy>
            <FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' />
          </OrderBy>
        </Query>
      </query>
      <viewFields>
        <ViewFields>
          <FieldRef Name="Category" />
          <FieldRef Name="Location" />
        </ViewFields>
      </viewFields>
      <queryOptions>
        <QueryOptions>
          <ViewAttributes Scope="RecursiveAll" />
          <RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>v3</RecurrencePatternXMLVersion>
          <DateInUtc>TRUE</DateInUtc>
          <ExpandRecurrence>TRUE</ExpandRecurrence>
        </QueryOptions>
      </queryOptions>
    </GetListItems>
  </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Put below code instead of the date time value.

```
 <DateRangesOverlap>
            <FieldRef Name="EventDate" />
            <FieldRef Name="EndDate" />
            <FieldRef Name="RecurrenceID" />
            <Value Type="DateTime"><Now /></Value>
          </DateRangesOverlap>
```

And for ordering put `<OrderBy><FieldRef Name='EventDate' Ascending='True' /></OrderBy>` after `</Where>`
Try different options mentioned in below link.

Remove the `<viewfields>`.

[Recurring Events](https://kartooz.wordpress.com/2009/02/20/querying-sharepoint-calendar-for-recurring-events-using-caml-query/)

Comment: When I try that, the service only returns two events, the first with `ows_EventDate='2019-05-23T00:00:00Z'` and the second `ows_EventDate='2019-07-27T00:00:00Z'`.  Any idea why it only returns two events!?  There should be an event for every week until 2038 (according to the event's `ows_EndDate='2038-09-11T23:59:00Z'`)!

Comment: if you use <Now /> then it will return the events of next two years from today's date.

Comment: Check this link for more details and to check how this options works.
http://www.sharepointnadeem.com/2015/05/sharepoint-recurring-calendar-events.html

Comment: When I use `<Now />` it returns 18 items but only 1 item from my "Merchandising" series which occurs every Saturday.  The one that it returns has `ows_EventDate='2019-07-27T00:00:00Z'` which is in the past.  Why would it be returning a past event when we asked for events after `<Now />`?

Comment: Can you please post the new query you are using ?? I  verified this with my list and it's giving expected output

Comment: Sure, I have updated the question with my latest code.  Thanks.

Comment: Remove the view fields and check if there is any change in results ?

Comment: Wow!  It works, but how can I use my `ViewFields`?  I would like to also fetch `Category` and `Location` of the events.  Is it not compatible?

Comment: Yes, with viewfields it gives weird results. For my case I retrieved the particular column value from list item

Comment: If you are satisfied with answer and it solved your events not retrieving issue then kindly accept the answer